# How has an increase in the complexity of systems affected successive generations of programmers?

Tags: programming-practices, theory

As a "new" programmer (I first wrote a line of code in 2009), I've noticed it's relatively easy to create a program that exhibits quite complex elements today with things like .NET framework for example. Creating a visual interface, or sorting a list can be done with very few commands now.

When I was learning to program, I was also learning computing theory in parallel. Things like sorting algorithms, principles of how hardware operates together, boolean algebra, and finite-state machines. But I noticed if I ever wanted to test out some very basic principle I'd learned in theory, it was always a lot more difficult to get started because so much technology is obscured by things like libraries, frameworks, and the OS.

Making a memory-efficient program was required 40/50 years ago because there wasn't enough memory and it was expensive, so most programmers paid close attention to data types and how the instructions would be handled by the processor. Nowadays, some might argue that due to increased processing power and available memory, those concerns aren't a priority.

My question is if older programmers see innovations like these as a godsend or an additional layer to abstract through, and why might they think so? And do younger programmers benefit more learning low-level programming BEFORE exploring the realms of expansive libraries? If so then why?

Comment: Joel Spolsky's article from 2002 is relevant: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html As phrase/formulated, however, this question might end up being considered primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I do lament the lack of more simple options for exploring very basic programming techniques.

Comment: Check out some of the articles on this blog (Programming in the 21st Century): [prog21.dadgum.com](http://prog21.dadgum.com). He talks a lot about modern computing power, effective infinite resources, and so on. It's also a great perspective of someone who did 8-bit game programming, and really knows the low level stuff.

Comment: [This is relevant.  Sort of.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/194206)  (I mean, I hope that image is a joke, but with some of what gets on to StackOverflow...)

Comment: "Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning." ([Rich Cook](http://quotes4all.net/rich%20cook.html))

Comment: It has its pros and cons. It opens the programming world to a lot of new programmers, who don't need as high skill to succeed - contrary to what some people might say, that's a good thing. And we're still writing efficient programs, that never changed - it's just that the goals have changed. Saving a byte on a year in date is no longer a good thing - the memory difference is usually unlikely to make a difference, and using eg. two bytes is more flexible and future-proof. Cost of programmers vs. cost of SW and HW is also a significant factor. The demand for new software is huge. Coders are few.

Comment: 40/50 yr timescale is wrong. Memory efficient programming was still critically important in 16 bit Windows (less than 20 years ago) and (unfortunately) in most embedded/robotics today.

Comment: +1 david.pfx and I know plenty of cases in just the last year (at a startup) which memory is an issue, for example java memory heap problems, oracle database memory space, local development machine memory (8gb wasn't enough) and I still work with programmers who try to save space with datatypes.

Comment: As an old programmer, I envy you. My earliest lines of code made the computer print 'I hate computers'. Years of study (without internet) later, I could make a white sprite move smoothly over a black background, which taxed my 8 bit computer to its limits. Kids starting today get to make a website or a mobile app. There is so much more stuff you can do! I hope I'll live long enough to see what wonders can be made by kids who have had computers and the internet around all their lives. I'd like to type up a longer post about this, but the page is locked.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

> it just isn't necessary because of the increased amount of processing power and memory available.

Having cheap memory, enormous disks and fast processors isn't the only thing that has freed people from the need to obsess over every byte and cycle. Compilers are now far, far better than humans at producing highly optimized code when it matters.

Moreover, let's not forget what we're actually trying to optimize for, which is value produced for a given cost. Programmers are way more expensive than machines. Anything we do that makes programmers produce working, correct, robust, fully-featured programs faster and cheaper leads to the creation of more value in the world.

> My question though is how do people feel about this "hiding" of lower-level elements. Do you older programmers see it as a godsend or an unnecessary layer to get through?

It is absolutely necessary to get any work done. I write code analyzers for a living; if I had to worry about register allocation or processor scheduling or any of those millions of other details then I would not be spending my time fixing bugs, reviewing performance reports, adding features, and so on.

All of programming is about abstracting away the layer below you in order to make a more valuable layer on top of it. If you do a "layer cake diagram" showing all the subsystems and how they are built on each other you'll find that there are literally *dozens* of layers between the hardware and the user experience. I think in the Windows layer cake diagram there's something like 60 levels of necessary subsystems between the raw hardware and the ability to execute "hello world" in C#.

> Do you think younger programmers would benefit more learning low-level programming BEFORE exploring the realms of expansive libraries?

You put emphasis on BEFORE, so I must answer your question in the negative. I'm helping a 12 year old friend learn to program right now and you'd better believe I'm starting them in [Processing.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing.js) and not x86 assembler. If you start a young programmer in something like `Processing.js` they'll be writing their own shoot-em-up games in about eight hours. If you start them in assembler they'll be multiplying three numbers together in about eight hours. Which do you think is more likely to engage the interest of a younger programmer?

Now if the question is "do programmers who understand layer n of the cake benefit from understanding layer n - 1?" the answer is yes, but that's independent of age or experience; it's always the case that you can improve your higher level programming by understanding better the underlying abstractions.

Comment: +1 fun citation: [Dunbars Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar's_number) is a good example (there are others) of studied cognitive capacity quotients that can be seen across many people showing that we do have a fixed mental space. Abstracting multiple things into singular generalizations is the only way we can cohesively increase the number of things in our mental space, and that's what higher level programming seeks to take advantage of.

Comment: I would like to ask question about your last paragraph. If you teach someone on Processing.js, wouldn't it create problems if they  wanted to learn something less abstract? Like C? Because they are so used to compiler/interpreter/libraries it would feel bad to go level down. Compare it to having to use shovel when all you ever used is excavator. Anyone would feel disilusioned. For example, many engineering students are fist taught to draw by hand before moving to CAD, just to make sure they learn proper basics.

Comment: @Euphoric: Your question makes sense but where do you stop?  Suppose I say "well, instead of learning Processing.js let's learn how to write video games in C++ using DirectX". OK, fine. Now what stops you from saying "isn't it going to create problems if they want to do something less abstract?" and so maybe we want to start with how to write a graphics card driver. But then you ask the question again, and before you know it, we're entering machine code into an Altair with toggle switches. You've got to pick a level of abstraction *somewhere*!

Comment: Good question. I think the end should be where you can learn most common stuff while keeping the details of hardware away. C sounds like a good candidate. You learn all the basics (if, for, methods, structures, data indirection {eg. pointers}, compilation) while not having to worry about hardware. For example our college uses C as introductory language and I'm thankful for that, because I couldn't learn many things otherwise .

Comment: @Euphoric: I agree that learning all that stuff is goodness. The problem is that C is so poorly implemented in most implementations -- optimizing for everything *but* programmer productivity and ease of learning -- that it scares away many people who would be decent programmers. There is no reason why a pedagogic C compiler needs to have "randomly corrupt memory" as its implementation of undefined behaviour!

Comment: I'm gonna say something before I stop arguing. Do we really need more "decent" programmers? I think no. We need great programmers. And if starting with C scares them away, then good. We don't need programmers who will make games in 8 hours in javascript+some library. We need programmers who understand the code they write and possible ramifications of it. And possibly being able to make the javascript interpreter itself. I believe starting with high-level language is not going to help this.

Comment: @Euphoric: Would you make the same argument to, say, accounting? We don't need more people who can keep the simple books for a new small business; we need GREAT, world-class accountants. If introductory accounting courses are so difficult that they scare away people who merely aspire to be productive, workmanlike accountants, GOOD. We don't need those people in the accounting industry! How about pianists?  If introductory piano lessons scare away people who are not going to be GREAT pianists, that's good; we only want great pianists in the world. Does something seem wrong with this argument?

Comment: @Euphoric: The short answer is GOOD HEAVENS YES we need more decent programmers! We need more programmers at every level of ability and experience. **The world runs on software**. The more people who have *any* understanding of how to make their world work, the better.

Comment: @Euphoric How do you suggest a programmer gets to being "Great" without being "Decent" at some point?

Comment: @Ampt Talent. While you can learn a lot with effort, different people have different limits. In this discussion, I assume we are talking about "maximum" what person can achieve. By great programmer, I mean someone who understands it's craft. By decent I mean someone who can code, but will never create code of complexity great programmer can.

Comment: @Euphoric (and others) - we're kind of hitting the limit regarding constructiveness of comments.  Please join us in [chat] if you would like to continue this conversation.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the 12 year old - if you teach assemble, they have a wonderful puzzle to get their mind around; if you teach them processing.js they get used to the idea of quick gratification, and may get fed up with harder coding problems that don't provide it. I think you might be underestimating the 12 year old.

Comment: I totally agree with learning layer N and N-1.  You really don't appreciate what languages/libraries are doing for you until you've had to deal with the layer below them.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I'd at least jump the 12-year-old up to something higher-level than assembly, and show how it can help them with their math homework.  I mean, it's how I got interested in programming - I got started with the TI-BASIC language included on the [TI-83 calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-83)

Comment: I started with QBasic then switching to C later didn't strike me as  being a terrible step backward at all. Stuff took more care, more code, but it was finally me in command; and the result thousands of times faster, and that was gratifying.

Comment: *"Programmers are way more expensive than machines."* is also something that's new, compared to 'before'.

Comment: @Benjol you are right. And Eric, let me add that not only the compiler, but also the basic libraries got better and better. I remember [this old "race"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx) between Raymond Chen and Rico Mariani, in which they compare performances and optimization between native and managed code. Raymond "won" in the end, but.. he is Raymond! :) And look at the effort!

Comment: My point is: just because it's "lower level" it does not mean it is slower, or more wasteful.. libraries benefit from years of experience of other programmers, people that often is more clever then me or knows better. And on modern architectures, gain performance at low level (with multiple level cache, alignment, branch prediction,..) is much harder than it used to be. I'd say: know it (you always need to know how it works), but leave it to the experts.

Comment: +1: *"All of programming is about abstracting away the layer below you in order to make a more valuable layer on top of it."* - I've also seen it phrased as *"Any problem in computer science can be solved by adding another layer of abstraction"*. ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Except of course the problem **I have too many levels of abstraction**. :-)

Comment: 10 years ago I programmed snake in QBasic in about 8 hours on a Windows box, worked right the first time too. I suppose for new programmers, language might not necessarily matter as much as the actual programming fundamentals (loops, if/else, etc), but the lower layers shouldn't be taken for granted by the same token, and should at least be *mentioned*.

Comment: And oh, you'd be fixing bugs all the time anyway if you used lower level languages. The point is, 99% of them would be bugs that simply wouldn't happen in the first place in a higher level language. Finding the right balance is another life-long job for a great programmer. One of the worst things any programmer can do is get him/herself locked in one language, one platform. Using the right tool for the job is extremely useful, as is deciding, whether it offsets the *cost* of doing so :)

Comment: @Euphoric: I agree with you that a great programmer should not only know JavaScript, but also C (and maybe Lisp, Haskell, and many others). But consider that there are many developer jobs that do not require any knowledge of C. As pointed out by others: a developer might be happy to be a good-enough programmer and earn a living, and there are plenty of jobs for such programmers.

Comment: @Giorgio: You are correct; an interesting statistic is: in the United States alone last year there were 150000 open jobs for programmers, and only 40000 computer science students graduated. I guarantee you that 90+ % of those graduates were not "great" programmers.

Comment: @Euphoric, on top of the fact that there's nothing wrong with training "merely" decent programmers, and I think the world needs more of them, I don't even think what you propose is a reliable method for determining level of talent. If someone is new to programming and is scared away by C being their introduction, it does not necessarily follow that this person does not have the capacity to be a great programmer. And for the list of basics that you mentioned, C is a terrible language to start with. If your goal is just the basics, a modern high-level language is better -- like ruby or python.

Answer (score 50):

I had ideas on this subject, and I [*put them into a book 20 years ago*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Building_Better_Applications.html?id=8A43E1UFs_YC).
It's long out of print, but you can [*still get used copies on Amazon*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0442017405).

One simple answer to your question is as old as Aristotle: [*Nature abhors a vacuum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_%28physics%29).
As much as machines have gotten faster and bigger, software has gotten slower and bigger.

To be more constructive, what I proposed was that information theory, and its direct relevance to software, be part of computer science education.
It is only taught now, if at all, in a very tangential way.

For example, the big-O behavior of algorithms can be very neatly and intuitively understood if you think of a program as a Shannon-type information channel, with input symbols, output symbols, noise, redundancy, and bandwidth.

On the other hand, the productivity of a programmer can be understood in similar terms using Kolmogorov information theory.
The input is a symbolic conceptual structure in your head, and the output is the program text that comes out through your fingertips.
The programming process is the channel between the two.
When noise enters the process, it creates inconsistent programs (bugs).
If the output program text has sufficient redundancy, it can permit the bugs to be caught and corrected (error detection and correction).
However, if it is *too* redundant it is too large, and its very size, combined with the error rate, *causes* the introduction of bugs.
As a result of this reasoning, I spent a good part of the book showing how to treat programming as a process of *language design*, with the goal of being able to define the domain-specific-languages appropriate for a need.
We do pay lip service to domain-specific-languages in CS education but, again, it is tangential.

Building languages is easy.
Every time you define a function, class, or variable, you are adding vocabulary to the language you started with, creating a new language with which to work.
What is not generally appreciated is that the goal should be to make the new language a closer match to the conceptual structure of the problem.
If this is done, then it has the effect of *shortening* the code and making it less buggy simply because, ideally, there is a 1-1 mapping between concepts and code.
If the mapping is 1-1, you might make a mistake and code a concept incorrectly as a different concept,
but the program will never crash, which is what happens when it encodes *no consistent requirement*.

We are not getting this.
For all our brave talk about software system design, the ratio of code to requirements is getting bigger, much bigger.

It's true, we have very useful libraries.
However, I think we should be very circumspect about abstraction.
We should not assume if B builds on A and that is good,
that if C builds on B it is even better.
I call it the "princess and the pea" phenomenon.
Piling layers on top of something troublesome does not necessarily fix it.

To terminate a long post, I've developed a style of programming (which sometimes gets me in trouble) where

- Invention is not a bad thing. It is a good thing, as it is in other branches of engineering. Sure it may be creating a learning curve for others, but if the overall result is better productivity, it is worthwhile.
- Haiku-style minimalist code. That *especially* goes for data structure design. In my experience, the biggest problem in software these days is bloated data structure.

Comment: This sounds very much what [Chuck Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Moore) (inventor of [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29)) has always advocated. For instance, from *[Chuck Moore's Comments on Forth](http://www.ultratechnology.com/moore4th.htm)*, "I do not think it is intrinsic in the nature of software that it has to be large, bulky, buggy. It is in the nature of our society. ... There is so much economic motivation for producing this ... bloatware, that I kind of feel irresponsible in standing up and saying the emperor has no clothes.".

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Agreed. It's lonely. There's a word for that - [*Cassandra complex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_(metaphor)).

Comment: While writing code artifacts to "extend" languages is not a difficult undertaking, making a good API that accurately and intuitively mirrors the problem domain *is.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You're right, and my attempts to do that have [*not all been well received :)*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15209065/23771)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey ~clicks link~ Oh yeah, you're that "differential execution" guy.  I remember thinking that what you described was straightforward _if_ you can get past the large explanation.  (And in terms of your answer here, I also have a tendency to create mini-DSLs so the rules can be put together succinctly.  I think, as RobertHarvey suggests, the people who are vehemently opposed just haven't seen/used/been forced to change a good implementation once the code is in maintenance)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: BTW: You are also the "no-profiler" guy (this is meant in a positive way). A few months ago, I again used [your technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) in the real world to swiftly reduce the load time of a document file from typically 25 seconds to 1 second (a load time the user directly experiences). It took a few iterations, and 10-20 samples in all iterations were more than sufficient. The performance problems were of course in unexpected places.

Comment: @Izkata and Peter: Yeah, I'm that oddball. FWIW, I put up a couple (extremely amateur) videos, in hopes of making it easier to understand. [*Random Pausing.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U) [*Differential Execution.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibPR17IZZUM) Cheers.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - Were not well received by echolot-1.  You can't please the whole internet.

Comment: What do you think of nimrod?  I am planning on learning it because it has great features like templates, importing function names from package into the scope (good for DSLs), and the packages are all in one git repo for people to make pull requests.  And what I consider to be a clean, minimalist, and easy to understand syntax (if you want to use it that way, you can get pretty advanced if you want).

Comment: @Jason: I plead ignorance of nimrod. What I look for in a DSL is if you write domain-specific programs in it, and a specific request or requirement comes along that's simple enough that you can either do it or not, then if you completely implement it, then you diff the source files before and after the implementation, the number of differences is small. (puff!)

Comment: Used copies going starting @ $137? No free PDFs anywhere? j/k, I agree with your answer :-)

Comment: @MDMoore313: I scanned it, and could send you that. It's 17mb.

Comment: I am also interested... Putting it in folder "Public" on a [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) account enables providing a public accessible download URL (that wouldn't be discoverable). (It could be taken down after a few days.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I just emailed it to you (17mb). Remember, it's 20 years old.

Comment: I love creating new languages. If only it was easier...

Comment: @david.pfx: When I worked in Lisp, macros were perfect for that. In C-like languages, I would first see if I could do it just using C macros (I hated that the Java-folks deprecated those), otherwise I write recursive-descent parsers. I've done so many now, it's almost sleepwalking.

Comment: @mike: I disliked Lisp because of the syntax: every DSL is still at some level just Lisp and yes, I've written a few parsers too. My main product has a macro language with recursion and types that is routinely used to extend the language, but debugging them is vile. I'm over macros.

Comment: @david.pfx: Agreed. Macros could use a debugger of their own :)

Answer (score 35):

High-level abstraction is essential to achieving ongoing progress in computing.

Why?  Because humans can only hold so much knowledge in their heads at any given moment.  Modern, large scale systems are only possible today because you can leverage such abstractions.  Without those abstractions, software systems would simply collapse under their own weight.

Every time you write a method, you're creating an abstraction. You're creating a bit of functionality that's hidden behind a method call.  Why do you write them?  Because you can test the method, prove it works, and then invoke that functionality any time you want just by making the method call, and you don't have to think anymore about the code that's inside that method.

In the early days of computing, we used machine language.  We wrote very small, bare metal programs with intimate knowledge of the hardware we were writing them for.  It was a painstaking process.  There were no debuggers; your program usually either worked, or it crashed.  There was no GUI; everything was either command-line or batch process.  The code you wrote would only work on that particular machine; it would not work on a machine with a different processor or operating system.

So we wrote high-level languages to abstract all of that detail away.  We created virtual machines so that our programs could be portable to other machines.  We created garbage collection so that programmers wouldn't have to be so diligent about managing memory, which eliminated a whole class of difficult bugs.  We added bounds checking to our languages so that hackers couldn't exploit them with buffer overruns.  We invented Functional Programming so that we could reason about our programs in a different way, and rediscovered it recently to take better advantage of concurrency.

Does all this abstraction insulate you from the hardware?  Sure it does. Does living in a house instead of pitching a tent insulate you from nature?  Absolutely.  But everyone knows why they live in a house instead of a tent, and building a house is a completely different ball game than pitching a tent.

Yet, you can still pitch a tent when it is necessary to do that, and in programming, you can (if you're so inclined) still drop down to a level closer to the hardware to get performance or memory benefits that you might not otherwise achieve in your high-level language.

---

Can you abstract too much?  "Overtake the plumbing," as [Scotty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_Scott) would say?  Of course you can.  Writing good API's is hard.  Writing good API's that correctly and comprehensively embody the problem domain, in a way that is intuitive and discoverable, is even harder.  Piling on new layers of software isn't always the best solution.  [Software Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) have, to some degree, made this situation worse, because inexperienced developers sometimes reach for them when a sharper, leaner tool is more appropriate.

Comment: +1, although I think you got the history of functional programming backwards (the lambda calculus predates electronic computers, and many functional languages predate concurrent programming).

Comment: I added a small clarification.

Comment: "In the early days of computing, we used machine language. We wrote very small, bare metal programs with intimate knowledge of the hardware we were writing them for."  Some of us in embedded programming are occasionally still doing that, on 8-but microcontrollers that have less than 1K of program memory, 64 bytes of RAM, and cost around a quarter.  No C compiler there.  (But I usually work with 32-bit microcontrollers with typically 1/2 MB of program space.)

Answer (score 9):

Really good training involves both extremes, as well as a bridge between.

On the low-level side: how a computer executes code from the ground up*, including knowledge of assembly language and what a compiler is doing.

On the high-level side: general concepts, e.g. using associative arrays, closures, etc. without having to waste time worrying about how it works under the hood.

IMHO everyone should have experience with both, including their drawbacks, and a taste of how to get from low-level concepts to high-level concepts. Love associative arrays? Great, now try using them on an 50-cent embedded processor with 1kB of RAM. Like writing fast code using C? Great, now you have three weeks to write a web app; you can spend your time dealing with data structures and memory management using C, or you can spend your time learning a new web framework and then implement the web app in a few days.

As far as the complexity aspect of it goes: I do think [it is too easy these days to make complex systems  without a clear understanding of the cost of doing so](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/132.php). As a result, we have, as a society, built up a huge amount of [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) that bites us from time to time. It's like earthquakes (just the cost of living near a geological fault, right?), only it's gradually getting worse. And I don't know what to do about it. Ideally we'd learn and get better at managing complexity, but I don't think that's going to happen. A responsible engineering education needs to include a lot more discussion of the consequences of complexity than most of our universities are currently providing.

---

* and, anyway, where is the "ground" in how a computer executes code? Is it assembly language? Or computer architecture? Or digital logic? Or transistors? Or device physics?

Answer (score 7):

I feel that high level programming has many advantages and is an essential part of a programming language. One of the reasons why Java become successful was that it has a comprehensive library. You achieve more with less code - just call a predefined function.

We can now distinguish programming language users from programming language writers (compiler writers). We leave the optimisations to compiler writers. We focus more on maintainability, reuse, etc

Answer (score 7):

The increase in the complexity of systems is relentless, oppressive and ultimately crippling. For me as an older generation programmer, it is also bitterly disappointing.

I've been programming for well over 40 years, having written code in 50-100 different languages or dialects, and become expert in 5-10. The reason I can claim so many is that mostly they're just the same language, with tweaks. The tweaks add complexity, making every language just a little different.

I have implemented the same algorithms innumerable times: collections, conversions, sort and search, encode/decode, format/parse, buffers and strings, arithmetic, memory, I/O. Every new implementation adds complexity, because every one is just a little different.

I wonder at the magic wrought by the high flying trapeze artists of the web frameworks and mobile apps, at how they can produce something so beautiful in such a short time. Then I realise how much they don't know, how much they will need to learn about data or communications or testing or threads or whatever before what they do becomes useful.

I learnt my craft in the era of fourth generation languages, where we genuinely believed that we would produce a succession of higher and higher level languages to progressively capture more and more of the repetitive parts of writing software. So how did that turn out, exactly?

Microsoft and IBM killed that idea by returning to C for writing apps for Windows and OS/2, while dBase/Foxpro and even Delphi languished. Then the web did it again with its ultimate trio of assembly languages: HTML, CSS and JavaScript/DOM. It's been all downhill from there. Always more languages and more libraries and more frameworks and more complexity.

We know we should be doing it differently. We know about CoffeeScript and Dart, about Less and Sass, about template to avoid having to write HTML. We know and we do it anyway. We have our frameworks, full of leaky abstractions, and we see what wonders can be done by those chosen few who learn the arcane incantations, but we and our programs are trapped by the decisions made in the past. It's too complicated to change or start over.

The result is that things that ought to be easy are not easy, and things that ought to be possible are nearly impossible, because of complexity. I can estimate the cost of making changes to implement a new feature in an established code base and be confident I'll be about right. I can estimate, but I can't justify it or explain it. It's too complicated.

In answer to your final question, I would strongly advise younger programmers to start as high on the layer cake as they possibly can, and only dive down to the lower layers as the need and desire provide the impetus. My preference is for languages with no loops, little or no branching and explicit state. Lisp and Haskell come to mind. In practice I always finish up with C#/Java, Ruby, Javascript, Python and SQL because that's where the communities are.

Final words: complexity is the ultimate enemy! Beat that and life becomes simple.

Comment: My 30+yrs of programming have taught me to use the highest level language available that will do what needs to be done and still allow the use of lower level languages when required. Easiest environment for that is shell scripting which can invoke modules written in any language. The hard part is breaking the dominant mindset that all functionalities of a project have to be implemented in the same language.

Comment: @dicsalvage: I agree, and my big disappointment is the lack of ever higher levels. What awk could do in 10 lines in the 1980s now take 15 lines in Ruby or Python, but I look for something to do it in 3. And the locked down environments on phones mean the same thing takes 50 in Java or Objective C. No shell scripts there!

Comment: Google "bash for android" shows a lot of folks working on ports. There's also versions of Python like [Kivy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Comment: @DocSalvage: Sooner or later the phone environment will join civilisation (as we know it). My complaint is the time taken to do over and over again the things that seem to have been finished. We keep having to go back to laying foundations and brickwork and drainage and shacks when I want to be building skyscrapers.

Answer (score 4):

> My question though is how do people feel about this "hiding" of lower-level elements. Do you older programmers see it as a godsend or an unnecessary layer to get through?

Neither, really.

Layering is necessary because without it, you reach a point where your system becomes unmaintainable spaghetti.  It's also one of the tenets of reusability:  if the developer of a library did a good job, the people using it shouldn't have to care about the details of the implementation.  The amount of canned code we use in our systems has grown by orders of mangitude from what it was when I wrote my first program 35 years ago.  That growth means we're able to do more powerful things as time goes on.  This is good.

The place where it's been a problem for me is entirely cultural.  My pragmatic half understands that it's no longer possible to wrap my mind around every last detail and be able to finish the things I want to get done.  (Getting older doesn't help, either.)  My cantankerous graybeard half had a difficult time letting go of many years of having such a fine-grained understanding of everything I worked on.

> Do you think younger programmers would benefit more learning low-level programming BEFORE exploring the realms of expansive libraries?

As has been pointed out in other answers, there's a balance to be struck between attracting and maintaining the attention of neophytes and giving them an ideal, from-the-bottom-up education.  If you can't do the former, the latter can't happen.

I see things in our industry that parallel the rest of society.  It used to be that almost everybody grew their own food and spent a lot of time doing that.  Since then, we've sprouted specialists called farmers who do that job, freeing up others to do other things that contribute to society.  I buy my food at a grocery store and would be thoroughly unable to produce most of it on my own if I had to.  We have a similar thing going on, albeit on a much more compressed time scale.  Programmers are specializing in some set of layers and not others.  The average guy writing GUIs may know that there is such a thing as swap space but probably doesn't know or care much about how the operating system is managing it.

The upshot of all this is that it's no longer about just development.  Continued specialization means developers will need to continue improving their communication and integration skills.

Answer (score 3):

As with everything, a little bit does you good, but too much hurts. The problem is too many systems don't know when to stop - just 1 more abstraction, to help you program faster... but then you end up coding in the real world where things are never quite as simple as you want, and you spend more time working round the edges than you would have spent with a less featured abstraction.

[Its ably described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6PX6.png)

[or here](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/GHOST-Busted.aspx) - "with a single line of code you could add 500 users to the domain"...

Your abstractions try to hide the complexity from you, but really all they do is hide that complexity. The complexity is still there, its just that you have much less control over it - and that's why you end up with this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Do younger programmers benefit more learning low-level programming BEFORE exploring the realms of expansive libraries? If so then why?

I don't think so. There are still plenty of situations in where it's beneficial to be aware of low the 'layer below' works, e.g.

- When debugging a problem on layer `n`, it's can often be explained by considering what happens on layer `n-1` (i.e. the layer below). I guess layer 0 would be "transistors" but if you want to explain a problem with transistors you would probably talk about physics (e.g. heat), so maybe physics is really level 0.
- When optimizing code it (unfortunately) does help at times to lower the level of abstraction, i.e. implementing an algorithm in terms of a lower-level layer. However, compilers became *really* good at doing this for you *if* they actually see all the code involved. This reason became more popular recently with the boom of mobile and embedded devices, which tend to have weaker processors and where "performance per Watt" is much more relevant than on, say, desktop systems.

In general however, it became a lot easier to make computers do stuff (even if in slightly inefficient ways) which means that there are a lot more programmers than there used to be. This in turn made the "human" factor much more important: [Robert Harvey's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/224151/10061) already mentioned that "humans can only hold so much knowledge in their heads at any given moment", and I think that's a very relevant aspect nowadays.

A major motivation in programming language and library (i.e. API) design is to make things easier on the human brain. To this day, everything still gets compiled down to machine code. However, this is not only error-prone, it's also notoriously hard to understand. So it's very desireable to

- Have the computer help you in finding logical errors in the programs you write. Things like static type systems or source code analyzers (I hear [Eric Lippert](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/224152/10061) works on a fairly popular one these days) help with that.
- Have a language which can be processed efficiently by a compiler *and* which communicates the *intent* of the programmer *to other programmers* to make working on the program easier. As an absurd extreme, imagine writing programs in plain english was possible. Fellow programmers might have an easier time to imagine what's going on but still, the description would be very hard to compiler into machine instructors, and it's notoriously ambiguous. So you need a language which a compiler can understan but which is *also* comprehensible.

Given that a lot of (most?) compilers are still very much general-purpose, they feature a very generic instruction set. There's no "draw a button" instruction or "play this movie". Hence, moving *down* the abstraction hierarchy makes you end up with programs which are very hard to comprehend and maintain (though trivial to compile). The only alternative is to move *up* the hierarchy, leading to more and more abstract languages and libraries.

Comment: And [below physics is math](https://xkcd.com/435/)

Answer (score 1):

"if older programmers see innovations like these as a godsend or an additional layer to abstract through, and why might they think so?"

I've been programming since I was in high school, about 34 years, starting with Basic and Z80 Assembler, moving to C, various 4GL languages, Scheme, SQL, and now various Web languages. The scope, scale, and depth of the problems addressed by the profession experienced an inflationary period over that time, particularly in the 1990's. Constructs such as libraries, frameworks, and OS services are all contrivances meant to address the complexity that goes along with the expanded space of problems.  They are not a godsend nor a burden in and of themselves - just a continued exploration of a vast solution space.

But, IMHO, "innovation" is better understood in terms of novel forms, and not mistaken for sideways movement - reintroducing forms we've already seen introduced. In some ways, the fecundity of an ecosystem suffers when the primitive forms don't compose, when they fixate decisions made early in the evolution, or can't reprocess their own detritus. Some, if not most, of the constructs we remain focused upon do not prioritize long-term sustenance of value as a concern. That has started changing - approaches like Service Orientation and Domain Driven Design, not to mention hypertext and graph-based models, for instance are altering the landscape. Like any ecosystem, eventually the dominant forms will give way to new forms; we are best served by allowing diversity, broadly and in small increments rather than large-scale top-down standardization followed by all-at-once collapse.

"And do younger programmers benefit more learning low-level programming BEFORE exploring the realms of expansive libraries? If so then why?"

I would argue that most human language is based on metaphors long since forgotten, so while I'd support learning low-level programming from a scientific/numeric literacy standpoint, it is more important that we seek primitives that will support the scale and scope of the problems we are tackling in a way that we can safely ignore the lower level of detail. A framework isn't a primitive, nor is an OS or a library - they are fairly poor at doing the kind of abstraction we really need. Real progress will take people who (a) know what went before and (b) can think in a novel enough manner to come up with something different enough to explore a space of solution that hasn't been explored before or was explored and forgotten.

OTOH, even if your goal is to work as a technician/mechanical level, some level of low-level programming exposure is still going to be helpful to developing your problem solving skills.

Answer (score 1):

My first program (as a 15 years old teenager) was in 1974 in [PL/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) on punched cards for an IBM 370/168 mainframe. My father was working at IBM and I was lucky enough to be able to go to the datacenter on Sundays.

At that time, a program of several thousands of statements (i.e.punched cards) was a big program (and a heavy one too, since many thousand of punched cards weighted many kilograms). Visual interfaces did not exist (a typical program read from its "standard input" using a punched card command starting with `//GO.SYSIN DD *` IIRC, but I did not master [JCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language)).
Algorithmics was important, and IIRC the standard library was quite small by today's standard.

Today, programs of several thousands lines are generally considered small. For example, the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has more than ten millions lines of source code, and *nobody* is understanding them fully.

My feeling is that programming today is quite different from the 1970s, because you need to use much more resources (in particular, existing libraries and software frameworks). However, I guess that people developing datacenter software (e.g. search engines at Google) or some embedded software care as much about algorithms and efficiency than the average programmer of the 1970s.

I still think that understanding low-level programming is important even today (even if most programmers won't code themselves basic container algorithms like balanced trees, dichotomically accessed sorted arrays, etc...) because understanding the whole picture is still important.

A major difference between the 1970s and today is the ratio of cost between developer's (human) efforts and computer power.